# nav-pill bootstrap not wroking on localhost hosted by xampp

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, xampp, nav-pills

```
<!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to implement the above given simple code on localhost hosted through XAMPP. amazingly the code works properly live without any issues. Any type of pointers will be appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: `amazingly the code works properly live without any issues` ???

Comment: @Anuresh the nav-pill class is also present on a website which is available on a live server

Comment: See the code works fine for me, except you have an additional  `</div>`

Comment: but at my end it redirect to the home page whenever i click on the <a> tag

Comment: have you attached required libraries (bootstrap.js) ?

Comment: yup i did that is why it is working fine on live

Comment: So this is working fine on ur live site and not on localhost. uh ?

Comment: exactly, that is what is happening..

Comment: Then am helpless here  , may try hard refresh to the browser (ctrl+f5)

Comment: i got  the solution :)  put: target="_self" in a tag and here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution :) 
put: target="_self" in a tag